How to model an optional user task in a default sequential flow of BPMN workflow
I have a requirement where I need to model an 'optional' user task.
When the workflow starts there is a chance that the user needs to perform one task, but that is not mandatory to proceed further in the flow. User may or may not perform that task.
The flow looks something like this:

I tried few options where it involved the use of sub-process, but not able to achieve the desired result.
Also, there is an option to remove the user-task from the flow completely, and behind the scene user can perform the task and workflow wouldn't know about it.
But, is there any way by which we can keep the user-task in the flow and make it optional?
Edit: I don't know if the optional task is going to be performed or not beforehand to add a conditional logic for exclusive gateway and decide the flow path.

There is one information missing: Who is deciding whether the optional task is to be performed? My guess is, it is the user. So the "optional task" is not really optional. The user must at least decide, whether she wants to do something. One option for completing the task could be "do nothing".

Until the user task has been completed, the next task cannot start. Maybe you rather wanted to say, that once the message arrived, the optional task is no longer relevant. For this you could use an interrupting message event on the border of the user task. The task would be in the work list of the user until the message arrives. So, if the user just ignores the task, it will eventually disappear from the list.

You have labeled the receive task with "... produce result". I think this is not allowed. The envelope icon says it is a receive task, so it cannot do something else. You can of course remove the envelope. A normal task can receive messages.

Thanks @AxelScheithauer,
Yes you are right, the user task is no longer needed once the message arrives and
the use of interrupting message event on the user task seems to fit my scenario.

The best way to do this is to add an exclusive gateway for the optional task: if the optional task is required, perform the optional task, if not, continue on with the process. Also, while modeling, be sure to always add a second gateway at the end of your gateway and decisions to ensure there is only one path the flow can take, as this is semantic BPMN.
Here is an example of what your model would look like with the exclusive gateway for the optional task:
BPMN model with optional user task
I would highly recommend taking a look at the Camunda docs and Camunda forum for more info, as well as Camunda Academy, which has free courses to learn more about BPMN.
Hope this helps!

Thanks @Samantha Holstine,
May be I didn't provide sufficient information in the question.
The thing is I don't know if the optional task is going to be performed or not beforehand to add a conditional logic for yes/no path, I know how exclusive gateway works but that is not suitable solution here.
